# how can I get coordinate from graphics2d.rotate

Tags: java, coordinates, graphics2d, drawrectangle

I have a trouble.
i want to see a drawed rectangle'coordinates when I use a g.drawImage(...)

```
g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), org_CenterX, org_CenterY);
g.drawImage(marskingimg, left, top, width, height, null);
ImageIO.write(org_bi, "jpg", org.getAbsoluteFile());
```

Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: You might be able to create an `Shape` and `transform` it, there might be a way to get the physical coordinates from that (I think I've seen it done before), otherwise, you'll need to brush up on your trig

Comment: Have a look at AffineTransform (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) you can transform any coordinats using it